# Better approach for getting the location coordinates

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-gps

I have successfully managed to get the current gps coordinates by calling requestLocationUpdates like this:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

if( provider != null){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }
```

And my "onLocationChanged" is updating this position according to my criterias.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.d(TAG, "location is" + location);
    double lat =  (location.getLatitude());
    double lng =  (location.getLongitude());
    String coordinates = (String.valueOf(lat) + "," + String.valueOf(lng));
    longitudeField.setText(coordinates);
}
```

Now in my app I want to pass the latitude and longitude to firebase together with an image and some other information.

So I have another method that is taking the url from captured image and sending the image to firebase together with two strings that are the current date and time.

```
private void uploadFile() {
    final String dateStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    final String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());

    if (mImageUri != null) {
        StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

        mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                            }
                        }, 500);


                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Upload upload = new Upload(
                                taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString(), timeStamp, dateStamp);


                        String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                        mDatabaseRef.child(dateStamp).child(uploadId).setValue(upload);


                    }
                })
```

**QUESTION:**

*How is the approach to getting the latitude and longitude in form of String so I can use it in my method for passing data to firebase?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend the following approach:

- keep track of current lat & current long globally(be it through [member variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html), or through the use of [shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)).
- Access these in your uploadFile method to send them.

Seems pretty straightforward to me.